# Getting ID into temp table variable on INSERT INTO ... OUTPUT ... INTO temp table

Tags: sql-server, insert-into

This is the sample procedure I am using.

```
create procedure PRO_ProcName
    @description varchar(max), 
    @txn_no varchar
as
begin
    declare @txn table (
        id bigint,
        description varchar(max),
        txn_no varchar
    );

    declare @txn_id bigint;

    insert into transactions    
    (
        description,
        txn_no
    )
    output
        inserted.description,
        inserted.txn_no
    into @txn
    values
    (
        @description,
        @txn_no
    )

    select @txn_id = id from @txn;
end
```

I am getting an error like:

`Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

I know that it is because I have `id` field in my temporary table and it is not getting inserted in the `insert into` statement. I cannot give value for `id` because it is the auto increment primary key.

How can I tackle this situation and get `id` of inserted record into a variable?

Comment: You can use inserted.id anyway whatever the column in the target table is auto increment primary key or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inserted` table represents the data that exists in the target table after the insert - so it also includes the auto-generated values, whether they where generated by a default value definition or by an identity definition on the columns - so you need to add `inserted.id` to the `output` clause.

However, there are two more things wrong in your procedure.
The first and most important is the fact that you didn't specify a length to the `@txn_no varchar` parameter. SQL Server will implicitly specify the length of 1 char in this case.
The second is the fact that you are not specifying the columns list of `@txn` in the `output` clause.

Here is a improved version of your code with all these issues fixed:

```
create procedure PRO_ProcName
    @description varchar(max), 
    @txn_no varchar(255) -- Note: I don't know the actual length you need
as
begin
    declare @txn table (
        id bigint,
        description varchar(max),
        txn_no varchar
    );

    declare @txn_id bigint;

    insert into transactions    
    (
        description,
        txn_no
    )
    output
        inserted.id,
        inserted.description,
        inserted.txn_no
    into @txn(id, description, txn_no)
    values
    (
        @description,
        @txn_no
    )

    select @txn_id = id from @txn;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot give value for id because it is the auto increment primary key.

No it isn't. You haven't declared it to be anything of the sort. So we need to fix that first:

```
declare @txn table (
    id bigint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    description varchar(max),
    txn_no varchar
);
```

And then we fix it by specifying a column list in your `INTO` clause:

```
output
    inserted.description,
    inserted.txn_no
into @txn (description, txn_no)
```

It's always a good habit to specify column lists anyway.

Or if I've misinterpreted your question, and the id should be coming from `transactions`, then you just add `inserted.id` as another column in your `OUTPUT` clause. `inserted` represents that state of the table after the insert. So you can include columns from it in your `OUTPUT` clause even if you didn't specify them in the `INSERT`.